# Android: reason for calling superclass?

Tags: android, superclass

I'm looking at the Notepad tutorial from the Android developer's site. I have a question about overridden functions calling the super-class of activities. For example,

```
public class Notepadv3 extends ListActivity {
    ...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(0, INSERT_ID, 0, R.string.menu_insert);
    return true;
    }
}
```

What's the point of the **super.onCreateOptionsMenu()**? I looked at the [developer's site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) and found this explanation:

*Call super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu) so the original menu items are created, then add new menu items with menu.add().*

But what original menu items are there?

Similarly, what's the point of other **super.(overridden_function)**, such as **super.onCreateContextMenu**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Activities have a number of operations they perform throughout their life cycle - some of these are house cleaning (garbage collection), UI stuff, etc.

As far as I know, **super.onCreateContextMenu()** doesn't have to be called, unlike methods like **onCreate**, **onResume**, etc.

Comment: Thanks Berdon. So **super.onCreate()** is necessary for life cycle management?

Comment: Yeah. Infact, if you don't call it a RuntimeException is thrown to let you know :).