# Menu not showing up

Tags: android

I have added a simple menu but its not showing up.

this is menu.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
    android:alphabeticShortcut="@string/settings_shortcut"
    android:title="@string/settings_label"></item>
    </menu>
```

this is main.java file-

```
  @Overridek
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

I just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: If you got the answer from anyone of below. Just accept their answer. Otherwise, it will be treat an unanswered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inflate your menu options in your `.java` file through this -

```
// Initiating Menu XML file (menu.xml)
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Hope [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/09/how-to-create-android-menus/) helps you lot.

Comment: thanx working now..but what if I call superclass menu,actually I got it from a tutorial. They added that line.

Comment: Just take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6968791/940096) You will be able to understand about `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);`

Answer (score 0):

You should delete this line : super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```