# Menu doesn't show up in android

Tags: android, menu

I have the below code and I can't understand why my code doesn't show up menu. If the activity containing data, `condition_true = true` otherwise `condition_true = false`. I can clearly see the control going to menutag and the condition is true too. Even I am getting `Inflated` string too in log. But still menu doesn't show up. I have seen lot of posts on these like [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968757/android-reason-for-calling-superclass/6968791#6968791), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257037/menu-not-showing-up) etc., but that didn't solve my problem. Can someone please help me on this issue?

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.clear(); //Clear view of previous menu
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        Log.d("menutag", condition_true);
        if(condition_true)
        {
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
             Log.d("menutag","Inflated");
        }

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu); // replaced this with true, but no use.
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the options attributes in xml.. Otherwise you can do it programmatically like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.yourmenuxmlfilename, menu);
    return true;
 }
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId){
    case R.id.item1:
       // what you want to do with first button
       break;
    case .....
       break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the difference between your code and my code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're overriding onKeyDown and it always returns true? This can cause the problem, because it will catch the menu button pressed event too.

Comment: No I didn't override onKeyDown(). I have inflated my custom layout in the sherlock actionbar. Sometimes it shows and sometimes it doesn't.